# SNMP management information base

Tags: 16.04, snmp, mib

I have a question that annoys me about SNMP protocol and more especially the MIB database. Well, I will try to put you in the context of the work: I will develop an application that allows me to query a SNMP agent to retrieve information about used memory, cpu etc. but the question is: What type of OID should I send?

I will begin to query virtual machines to test the application. The OS of the VMs is ubuntu.

What bothers me is that I do not understand the MIB table.

```
Is the MIB table propitious to each constructor or operating system?
If it is linked to an SE where I can find the ubuntu MIB files?
```